# Is it good idea to include horizontally scrollable content inside swipeable tabs

Tags: android, scrolling

As title says, i saw an app with swipeable tabs that had horizontally scrolling tabs and i would like to know others opinion whther nested scrolling hinders with user experience or not.

Comment: Well it really depends. Like if the horizontally scrolling content takes up the whole screen or not; if the swipable vs. scrollable areas are clearly separated, if they're large enough, their position on the screen, is the difference based on location vs swipe speed vs number of fingers, etc. I mean it could have no effect, or it could ruin the application, depending on how its implemented. A screen shot and a little more detail may help here.

Comment: The conent covers the whole screen,and there are two tabs at top. When you scroll till end, after scrolling is complete it starts to swipe to the other tab.

Comment: And did you like it? Or did you find it frustrating? The main problem I see with that is when you know you want to switch tabs but are forced to scroll through the content to get there; but whether or not you'd ever want or need to do that does depend somewhat on the nature of the application, of course.

Comment: Actually that UI was shown to me in an interview and i was asked ow would you make it, i did not see it that much but i have always avoided nested scrolling so wanted to ask some UX designers about their take on it. Thanks.